# Codeigniter PyroCMS -> Navigation Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, navigation

I have a box on the site of my page layout that displays the navigation for the particular section the user is in:

Example:

Food -> main heading witch is the page heading - I have this working fine
Apples
Oranges
Pears

Is there anyway that I could show the navigation for the specific page? I could use a group but then I would have a double up of links - if I am thinking correct I have 4 navigation menus with dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with CSS

Check my [site](http://arbioperu.org/home/porque-esta-region/)

#nav_2 li.current ul, #nav_2 li.has_current ul {
    visibility: visible;
    display: inline;
   }

#nav_2 li.current, #nav_2 li.has_current {
    background: #dee5d7;
   }

#nav_2 li ul{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
   }

Comment: I want to show the specific dropdown navigation links in a specific box dependent on witch menu the item was selected from.